# Перевод вещественных чисел в разные системы счисления

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

Поставлена задача:

> Разработать программу представления вещественного числа в одной из четырех
> систем счисления (двоичная, десятичная, восьмеричная, шестнадцатеричная).
>
> Программа должна выполнять чтение числа в одной из систем счисления и
> переводить в остальные системы счисления на выбор пользователя.
> Реализовать интерфейс пользователя.

Я пытался решить поставленную задачу различными способами, но не догадался как можно решить проблему с переводом в десятичную часть, для дальнейшей программы.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

char digit(int num) // Отображение шестнадцатеричной цифры
{
  switch (num) {
  case 0: return '0';
  case 1: return '1';
  case 2: return '2';
  case 3: return '3';
  case 4: return '4';
  case 5: return '5';
  case 6: return '6';
  case 7: return '7';
  case 8: return '8';
  case 9: return '9';
  case 10: return 'A';
  case 11: return 'B';
  case 12: return 'C';
  case 13: return 'D';
  case 14: return 'E';
  case 15: return 'F';
  }
} 

using namespace std;


int end_ch_int(int a, int p, char *s)// Получение целой части числа
{
  int num = a;
  int rest = num % p;
  num /= p;
  if (num == 0)
  {
    s[0] = digit(rest); return 1;
  }
  int k = end_ch_int(num, p, s);
  s[k++] = digit(rest);
  return k;
}

void end_ch_double(double a, int p, char *s)// Получение дробной части числа
{
  int iter = 0;
  int k = 0;
  double a1 = a;
  do {
    a1 = a1 * p;
    int num = (a1);
    s[k++] = digit(num);
    a1 -= a1;
    iter++;
  } while (a1 > 0.00000001 && iter < 10);
  s[k] = '\0';
}
int main()
{
  double a;
  char s[80] = { 0 };
  int p,d;
  system("cls");
  cout << "Введите число: ";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Введите начальную системы счисления: ";
  cin >> d;
  cout << "Введите конечную систему счисления: ";
  cin >> p;
  int k = end_ch_int(a, p, s);
  s[k++] = ',';
  end_ch_double(a-a, p, &s[k]);
  cout << s;
  cin.get(); cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: то что Вы написали не совсем то что нужно, читайте как переводятся числа и одной системы в другую. Вообще говоря например при переводе из 10-й в другие системы, для вещественных чисел нет однозначного перевода, не все числа можно перевести точно, а только приближение https://www.yaklass.ru/p/informatika/11-klass/kodirovanie-informatcii-predstavlenie-informatcii-v-kompiutere-18699/perevod-drobnykh-chisel-iz-odnoi-sistemy-schisleniia-v-druguiu-18700/re-c387b19c-2d8f-4cd7-a86f-e4891740d3be

Comment: У вас в начале программы есть уже число в десятичном виде,, Просто выведите это число `а`,  Или пусть ваша функция вернет свой первый аргумент, или сделайте функцию методом структуры, которая хранит это число.  *Так что  переводить в десятичную систему нет надобности.*

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я тут попробовал набросать. Погрешность накапливается быстро...

Вобщем, только для положительных чисел, только для систем от 2 до 36, с ограниченным количеством переводов между системами (накопление ошибки)...

```
int num(char c)  // цифра в некоторой системе счисления
{
    const char digs[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return int(strchr(digs, tolower(c)) - digs);
}

// Строка с числом в системе счисления base в double
// Защиты от дурака нет!
double toNum(const char* s, int base)
{
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) throw range_error("Wrong base");
    const char* c;
    double r = 0;
    for (c = s; *c && *c != '.'; ++c)
        r = r * base + num(*c);
    if (*c == '.')
    {
        for (double bs = base; *++c && bs > 0; bs *= base)
            r += num(*c) / bs;
    }
    return r;
}

// Число double в строку в системе счисления base, с prec знаков после точки
// Защиты от дурака нет!
string fromNum(double x, int base, int prec = 6)
{
    const char digs[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) throw range_error("Wrong base");
    int d = floor(x);
    string r;
    if (d == 0) r = "0";
    else
    {
        while (d)
        {
            r += digs[d % base];
            d /= base;
        }
        reverse(r.begin(), r.end());
    }
    x = x - floor(x);
    if (x && prec > 0)
    {
        r += '.';
        for (int i = 0; i < prec; ++i)
        {
            x *= base;
            r += digs[int(x)];
            x = x - floor(x);
        }
    }
    return r;
}


// Простенький тест...   
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string seven = "1234.56";
    cout << "orig: " << seven << endl;
    double x = toNum(seven.c_str(), 7);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    string elev = fromNum(x, 11, 20);
    cout << "11: " << elev << endl;


    x = toNum(elev.c_str(), 11);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    elev = fromNum(x, 4, 20);
    cout << "4: " << elev << endl;


    x = toNum(elev.c_str(), 4);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    elev = fromNum(x, 7, 20);
    cout << "7: " << elev << endl;
}
```

Смотреть [здесь](https://ideone.com/7yit22)...

Comment: Точный перевод может/должен использовать ту же технологию, что и печать дробей в виде десятичной дроби с периодом.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Можете показать в действии?